# How to set a video opacity to a linear-gradient opacity on text hover?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I have a `video` nested in a parent `div`. I would like to set its `opacity` to a `linear-gradient` transparency effect from `left to right, 100% to 0%`. The idea is to see the video at `100% opacity` on the left side and at `0%` on the right side.

*CONTEXT:* The overall goal is to blend two videos together with a different `linear-gradient` `opacity` when hovering different `text-item` elements.

My current code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="media">
  <video class="media__item" autoplay muted>
    <source src="src.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser doesn't support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.media {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
}

.media__item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 50%; /* this is wrong */
}
```

Comment: You'd have to use an overlay with a gradient....but I suspect that this will not give you the effect you are after. You can't apply `opacity` to **part** of an element.

Comment: yeah, that's what I don't wanna do. :-( The overall goal is to blend two videos together with a `linear-gradient` `opacity` between two videos on a `text-item` `hover`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can do that. I'm not overly familiar with it but you *might* be able to do something with `canvas` but that's another question.

Comment: yes, I'll look into it. Thank you =)

Comment: `mask-image` should do what you need.

Comment: Oooh...that's a decent suggestion. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

Comment: True, trying to see if it works with videos.

Comment: `mask-image:linear-gradient(to right, white,transparent)` should do it

Comment: Thank you, I will use that and check into `canvas` effects later.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understood from your question is that you want to play the video like normal but just have an overlay of linear-gradient over it so the code below shows the linear gradient facing to the right from black to zero opacity

hope this code helps you with your journey

```css
.media{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, rgba(19, 19, 19, 0));
    }
    
.media__item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

}
```

```html
<div class="media">
      <video class="media__item" autoplay muted>
        <source src="src.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser doesn't support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
```